# Get Custom logout url through Apex code

Tags: apex

In Setup >> Administer >> Security Controls >> Session Settings >> System Admin can define Logout Page URL.
Can we get this url through Apex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `SessionManagement Class` you have a method `getCurrentSession()` that return a map that includes the LogoutURL.

**getCurrentSession()**

Returns a map of attributes for the current session.

**Signature**

public static Map<String, String> getCurrentSession()

**Return Value**

Type: Map<String, String>

**Usage**

The map includes a ParentId value, which is the 18-character ID for the parent session, if one exists (for example, if the current session is for a canvas app). If the current session doesn’t have a parent, this value is null. The map also includes the `LogoutUrl` assigned to the current session.

Comment: If mentioned method retrieves logout url, please add it to answer.

Comment: If you check the details, the map also includes LogoutUrl